# keeping SignalR client connection alive

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr.client

If my SignalR client connection goes down, I want the client to attempt to reconnect.  Is this a good pattern for implementing this?  I am referring to handling the Closed event on the SignalR connection by restarting the connection.

```
public class OnPremiseWebHubClient
{
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private IHubProxy _hubProxy;

    private OnPremiseWebHubClient() { }
    static OnPremiseWebHubClient() { }
    private static readonly OnPremiseWebHubClient _instance = new OnPremiseWebHubClient();
    public static OnPremiseWebHubClient Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://OnPremiseWeb/");
        _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("OnPremiseHub");

        // IS THIS A GOOD PATTERN FOR KEEPING THE CONNECTION ALIVE?
        _hubConnection.Closed += async () =>
        {
            // reconnect if we close
            await _hubConnection.Start();
        };

        await _hubConnection.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR has own reconnect mechanism. But after some of retries the state will change to disconnected/Closed. Disconnected/Closed state means signalr tried reconnect but it couldn't achive. So it's good place to apply reconnect there for continuously reconnect.

There is one drawback: On mobile this reconnects will use battery.

You can check [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect) for more detail.